# How can I prevent JPA from setting an embeddable object to null just because all its fields are null?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Although counterintuitive and apparently not required by the JPA standard, both Eclipselink and Hibernate go to great lengths to create the following source of NullPointerExceptions: When all fields of an object embedded in an entity are null, then they replace the field itself by null. Here is a simplified example:

```
@Embeddable
public class Period {
    private Date start;
    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    private Date end;
    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    public boolean equals(Period other) { // TODO: implement hashCode()!
        return Objects.equals(start, other.start) && Objects.equals(end, other.end);
    }
}

@Entity
public class PeriodOwner {
    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({...})
    private Period period;
    public Period getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }
}
```

The idea is that we can write things like `po1.getPeriod().equals(po2.getPeriod())`. We pay for this by an additional degree of indirection when accessing the `Date` fields directly: `po1.getPeriod().getStart()`. This is often a good trade-off, but not when we have to write `po1.getPeriod() == null ? null : po1.getPeriod().getStart()` instead because our JPA provider loves null.

How can we make sure `getPeriod()` never returns null? Unfortunately, in standard JPA there exist neither Java annotations nor XML settings to solve this problem either globally or for specific embeddings or embeddables.

Answer (score 8):

**Official solution for Eclipselink**

For each affected entity write a separate `DescriptorCustomizer` implementation as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Nullable_embedded_values) and make it active using the `@Customizer` annotation as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_customizer.htm). Without tricks we cannot use the same customizer for every class affected, as the customizer needs to know the names of the embeddable fields for which it is to invoke `setIsNullAllowed(false)`.

Here is a universal `DescriptorCustomizer` implementation that can be used to make every embeddable from among a fixed list of classes non-nullable:

```
public class MyUniversalDescriptorCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    private static final ImmutableSet<Class> NON_NULLABLE_EMBEDDABLES = ImmutableSet.of(Period.class);

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        Class entityClass = cd.getJavaClass();
        for (Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (NON_NULLABLE_EMBEDDABLES.contains(field.getType())) {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
                AggregateObjectMapping aom = (AggregateObjectMapping) cd.getMappingForAttributeName(field.getName());
                aom.setIsNullAllowed(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To fix the null problem in our specific example, we have to modify `PeriodOwner` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Customizer(MyUniversalCustomizer.class)
public class PeriodOwner {
    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({...})
    private Period period = new Period();
    public Period getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }
}
```

Note that in addition to the `@Customizer` annotation, we also initialize the field `period` with `new Period()` because otherwise new Entities would still have null `period` fields.

**Official solution for Hibernate**

Apparently, since Hibernate 5.1 there is a setting `hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled`. (Since I am not using Hibernate, I didn't try to find out where this setting goes.)

**Pedestrian workaround**

The following takes care of the problem without polluting the code too much, but it's still quite messy.

```
@Embeddable
public class Period {
    private Date start;
    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    private Date end;
    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    public boolean equals(Period other) { // TODO: implement hashCode()!
        return Objects.equals(start, other.start) && Objects.equals(end, other.end);
    }

    public static Period orNew(Period period) {
        return period != null ? period : new Period();
    }
}

@Entity
public class PeriodOwner {
    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({...})
    private Period period;

    public synchronized Period getPeriod() {
        return period = Period.orNew(period);
    }
}
```

Note that `synchronized` is required for thread safety.

**Simple hack for Hibernate**

Instead of the above changes to `Period` and `PeriodOwner`, add one unused private non-null field to `Period`. For example:

```
@Formula("1")
private int workaroundForBraindeadJpaImplementation;
```

By using `@Formula` (a Hibernate extension) we avoid adding an extra column for this field in the database. This solution was described by Tomáš Záluský [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324266/can-i-make-an-embedded-hibernate-entity-non-nullable). It may be useful for those who want to change the behaviour only in some cases.

Comment: AFAIK, if you use synchronized around accessing a variable you don't need volatile. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Thanks. I have removed `volatile` as it does seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: Hibernate hack does not work with '0' value. Works with `@Formula("1")`

Comment: @vladimir83: That seems strange. But to be safe I just changed this from 0 to 1 in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the official Hibernate solution (in the current version 5.4) is still an "experimental" feature that should not be used in production. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_misc_options https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11936

Answer (score 3):

The JPA spec totally ignores handling of null embedded objects and leaves it up to implementations to do what they feel like (nice, yes?). [It has been requested for JPA 2.2+](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/42) but who knows if Oracle will ever bother to provide that.

DataNucleus JPA provides 2 extension properties for an embedded field/property

```
@Extension(key="null-indicator-column", value="MY_COL")
@Extension(key="null-indicator-value", value="SomeValue")
```

and so when the embedded object is null then this column is set to this value, and likewise when reading in objects it can detect a null embedded object and return it correctly to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution might be to initialize the object like so:

```
@Embedded
private InternalSalesStatistics internalSalesStatistics = new InternalSalesStatistics();
```

This covers the case when objects are created during runtime and then persisted.

To cover the case when an object was loaded from DB but the embeddable was initialized with null because all values were null:

```
@PostLoad
public void fixNullableEmbeddable() {
    if(internalSalesStatistics == null)
        internalSalesStatistics  = new InternalSalesStatistics();
}
```

I'm not absolutely sure that this has no side effects. During my tests it worked. I set values on the embeddedable that was initialized with PostLoad and the entity manager persisted it correctly.