# JPA Embedded and BeanValidation

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, bean-validation

```
@Entity    
public class Foo {

    [...]

    @Valid
    @Embedded
    private Poo poo;
}

@Embeddable
public class Poo {

    @NotNull
    private Double value;

    @NotNull
    private Double value2;

    [...]
}
```

I need to save the class Poo as null in the database and consequently any attribute that already exists in the table is converted to null. It's possible?

The only way I could do it was to remove @NotNull from the attributes and set each attribute itself to null.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Nullable_embedded_values on how to specify how EclipseLink should handle nulls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had the same problem and I solved it by adding an Annotation like @NotNull just underneath the annotation @Valid

```
    @Entity    
public class Foo {

    [...]

    @Valid
    @Embedded
    @NotNull
    private Poo poo;
}

@Embeddable
public class Poo {

    @NotNull
    private Double value;

    @NotNull
    private Double value2;

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default for me it works exactly as you said. I just tested it with MariaDB and:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here's my test code:

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    Foo foo = new Foo(1, new Poo(1, 2));
    validate(validator, foo);
    entityManager.merge(foo);

    List<Foo> fooList = entityManager
        .createNamedQuery(Foo.FIND_ALL, Foo.class)
        .getResultList();
    assertTrue(fooList.get(0).getPoo().getValue1() == 1);

    foo.setPoo(null);
    validate(validator, foo);
    entityManager.merge(foo);

    fooList = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery(Foo.FIND_ALL, Foo.class)
            .getResultList();

    assertTrue(fooList.get(0).getPoo() == null);
```

But if you still have a problem, please, provide your test scenario and check out this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979958/7974082 .