# How to edit Hibernate settings in a Spring-Boot project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to add this property change to hibernate so I can enable instantiation of composite/embeddable objects when all of its attribute values are null:

```
hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled
```

I am aware that the usual way to edit Hibernate is in the application.properties file like so:

```
################################################################################
#                               JPA MANAGEMENT                                 #
################################################################################
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true...
...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled=true
```

But the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled=true` isn't working. I'm not sure if Spring just doesn't recognize certain properties or if it's just the wrong place to put it.

What I'd like to know is if there is another way to edit the Hibernate properties directly or if there is another fix.

Comment: The related question: [Can I make an embedded Hibernate entity non-nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324266/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Analysis

The base assumption. More likely you are using Spring Boot 1.5.*.

1. Spring Boot 1.5.* uses Hibernate 5.0.*. [GitHub proof](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L88).
2. Hibernate supports the `hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled` setting since the 5.1 version.

   - [GitHub proof](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java#L1580).
   - JIRA proof (?): [[HHH-7610] Option for injecting empty (non-null) embedded when all columns are NULL - Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7610).
   - Release notes proof: [ORM 5.1 feature release](http://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/).

## Solution

Please consider upgrading the Hibernate dependency in your `pom.xml` to a more recent version (5.1 and higher).

After that, it should work just fine:

> In addition all properties in `spring.jpa.properties.*` are passed through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the local `EntityManagerFactory` is created.
>
> — [Spring Boot 1.5.* reference, 77. Data Access, 77.5 Configure JPA properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties).